# How to link views module with customized mysql

Tags: views, 7, database

I'm a newbie to drupal. I just got a web designing work. My client asked me to create a system somehow like [this](http://www.visitorsinsurance.ca/).

Basically, you enter your age and then hit submit; the result page will be a list of data that are automatically calculated based on the age value you provided.

I looked at the code, it seems the website uses drupal views module to list tables.

I want to know how did they achieve this. Did they put all data into nodes and retrieve them via views.

The deadline is almost there (Mar 21). I've already done the design of other part of the website using php and mysql. I want to integrate my development with drupal (because it's easy for clients themselves to maintain).

I don't need to complete the whole website design by Mar 21, but at least to demonstrate that I can build such system (perhaps a demo with fake data) so that I can extend the deadline a little bit.

Could anybody help? perhaps give me a direction on what to look and learn.

ps. I heard there's a data module in drupal, could I combine it with views to achieve the goal.

Comment: What you want is to use exposed filter in views. Are you asking for a full tutorial on how to use views? Because I doubt you will get that here. this may be a good place to start. http://bit.ly/15cq3nm

Comment: Thank you for your gently comment. I now have a customized database table (which has no connections with other tables of drupal) and want to integrate it with the views module. Is there a way to implement this?